# Remove the first element from link list in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm having difficulty removing the first element from a Link List in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    struct node *head;
} linklist;

void insertElement(linklist *list, node* curr);
void removeStart(node *curr);

int main(void){
    int i;
    node *curr;
    linklist *list;

    list = (linklist*)malloc(sizeof(linklist)); /* create head node */
    list->head = NULL;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        curr->data = i;

        curr->next = list->head; /* insert element to start */
        list->head = curr;       /* "                     " */
    }

    curr = list->head; /* traverse link list to start */

    insertElement(list, curr);

    curr = list->head;

    removeStart(curr);

    curr = list->head;

    while(curr != NULL) 
    {
            printf("%d\n", curr->data);
            curr = curr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void insertElement(linklist *list, node *curr){
    curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr->data = 4;
    curr->next = list->head;
    list->head = curr;
}

void removeStart(node *curr){
    node *tmp;

    tmp = curr;
    curr = curr->next;

    free(tmp);
}
```

When the code is compiled the final result should be:

3
2
1
0

Could someone please offer some suggestions on how I should go about this, also seperately how could a set it up to also remove any of the nodes in the link list. Thanks.

Comment: Think of what you would do using pencil and paper. Try to translate that into C++. If you still have questions, post what you have tried.

Comment: Your insertion logic is wrong.

Comment: Both functions `insertElement` & `removeStart` returns `struct node *` , but your callers do not collect them. Subsequently you are working on `curr` which points to older address I guess.

Comment: @SunEric I've changed the return types, still the same problem. How do I update the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. At least the output coincides with the output you showed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list 
{
    struct node *head;
} linklist;

void insertElement( linklist *list, int value )
{
    node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    tmp->data = value;
    tmp->next = list->head;

    list->head = tmp;
}

void removeStart( linklist *list )
{
    if ( list != NULL && list->head != NULL )
    {
            node *tmp = list->head;
            list->head = list->head->next;
            free( tmp );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    node *tmp;
    linklist list;

    list.head = NULL;

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) insertElement( &list, i );

    insertElement( &list, i );
    removeStart( &list );

    for ( tmp = list.head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", tmp->data );
    }

    for ( tmp = list.head; tmp != NULL;  )
    {
        node *current = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        free( current );
    }

    return 0;
}

3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Your `removeStart()` function leaks memory.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Thanks, I came up with a solution that was some what different.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Thanks. I uodated the function.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    struct node *head;
} linklist;

void insertElement(linklist *list, node* curr);
void removeStart(linklist *list);

int main(void){
    int i;
    node *curr;
    linklist *list;

    list = (linklist*)malloc(sizeof(linklist)); /* create head node */
    list->head = NULL;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        curr->data = i;

        curr->next = list->head; /* insert element to start */
        list->head = curr;       /* "                     " */
    }

    curr = list->head; /* traverse link list to start */

    insertElement(list, curr);

    curr = list->head;

    removeStart(list);

    curr = list->head;

    while(curr != NULL) 
    {
            printf("%d\n", curr->data);
            curr = curr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void insertElement(linklist *list, node *curr){
    curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr->data = 4;
    curr->next = list->head;
    list->head = curr;
}

void removeStart(linklist *list){
    node *tmp = NULL;
    if(list->head != NULL)
    {
    tmp = list->head;
    list->head = list->head->next;
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```